# Complex manipulations with matching arrays with JOLT

Tags: json, jolt

I have JSON looks like:

```json
{
  "query": {
    "ids": [
      72659413
    ],
    "dimensions": [
      "ym:s:gender"
    ],
    "metrics": [
      "ym:s:visits",
      "ym:s:pageviews"
    ]
  },
  "data": [
    {
      "dimensions": [
        {
          "name": "male",
          "id": "male"
        }
      ],
      "metrics": [
        [
          //in this array metric is ym:s:visits 
          121, //2022-06-10
          15,  //2022-06-11
          4    //2022-06-12 
        ],
        [
          //in this array metric is ym:s:pageviews
          87,
          11,
          2
        ]
      ]
    },
    {
      "dimensions": [
        {
          "name": "female",
          "id": "female"
        }
      ],
      "metrics": [
        [
          43,
          1,
          5
        ],
        [
          67,
          4,
          12
        ]
      ]
    }
  ],
  "time_intervals": [
    [
      "2022-06-10",
      "2022-06-10"
    ],
    [
      "2022-06-11",
      "2022-06-11"
    ],
    [
      "2022-06-12",
      "2022-06-12"
    ]
  ]
}
```

So, what is the goal?
I want to grab id from **ids** array inside `query`. Also from `query` I need values from `metrics` array.

Next step is grab values from `data` array. Values inside metrics array contain multiple arrays. Inside each array there are values sorted by date. Each array inside `metrics` matches with `metrics` array inside `query`.

And finally I need to add `query.dimensions` as property name and `data.dimensions.name` as property value.

Summary...

1. Value from `query.ids`
2. Metrics names from `query.metrics`
3. Dimensions names from `query.dimensions`
4. Metrics values from `data.metrics`
5. Dimensions values from `data.dimensions.name`
6. Match metrics names and metrics values through arrays
7. Match dimensions names and dimensions values through arrays

I hope I explained correctly.
I expect to get:

```json
[
  {
    "id": 72659413,
    "date": "2022-06-10",
    "ym:s:visits": 121,
    "ym:s:pageviews": 87,
    "ym:s:gender": "male"
  },
  {
    "id": 72659413,
    "date": "2022-06-11",
    "ym:s:visits": 15,
    "ym:s:pageviews": 11,
    "ym:s:gender": "male"
  },
  {
    "id": 72659413,
    "date": "2022-06-12",
    "ym:s:visits": 4,
    "ym:s:pageviews": 2,
    "ym:s:gender": "male"
  },
  {
    "id": 72659413,
    "date": "2022-06-10",
    "ym:s:visits": 43,
    "ym:s:pageviews": 67,
    "ym:s:gender": "female"
  },
  {
    "id": 72659413,
    "date": "2022-06-11",
    "ym:s:visits": 1,
    "ym:s:pageviews": 4,
    "ym:s:gender": "female"
  },
  {
    "id": 72659413,
    "date": "2022-06-12",
    "ym:s:visits": 5,
    "ym:s:pageviews": 12,
    "ym:s:gender": "female"
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use three level of successive **shift** transformations such as

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "data": {
        "*": {
          "metrics": {
            "*": {
              "@(4,query.ids[&])": "[&3].id",
              "@": "[&3].@(5,query.&2[&1])",
              "@(2,dimensions[&].name)": "[&3].@(5,query.dimensions[&])",
              "*": {
                "@(5,time_intervals[&][&3])": "[&4].date"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "ym:s:p*": {
          "*": {
            "@(2,id)": "&3.&1.id",
            "@(2,date[&])": "&3.&1.date",
            "@(2,ym:s:visits[&])": "&3.&1.ym:s:visits",
            "@": "&3.&1.&2",
            "@(2,ym:s:gender)": "&3.&1.ym:s:gender"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": ""
      }
    }
  }
]
```

where determine each attribute as arrays individually within the first one,
then dissipate each to their respective object within the second, and get rid of objects' ordinal key names finally.

the ***demo*** on the site http://jolt-demo.appspot.com/ is

[image]